# How do I call default method of interface provided by Class<?> object?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I need to call default method of interface (and get the returned value), but the interface is provided by Class object. (There is no other way to pass it then Class in my project)

Here is an example:
Let's imagine I have interface:

```java
public interface IExample {
     void someOtherAbstractMethod();
     default String method() {
         return "Test";
     }
}
```

Now imagine I have method

```
String getReturnValueOfInterfaceMethod(Class<T> clazz, String method_name) throws Exception {
    if (!clazz.isInterface()) return null;
    Method m = clazz.getMethod(method_name);
    if (!m.isDefault()) throw new Exception();
    // invoke the method and return the value ("Test")
}
```

**It is for complicated project, this is only an example!!!!**

My only idea is to invoke the method using `Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`, but I need an instance. So I think I need to **create an instance of anonymous class from that interface** (Other methods implement as empty or return default values). How do I do that? Or is there any other way to do that **without changing the IExample definition**.

Thanks!

Comment: Time to take a step back and look again at the requirement you need to solve for. This is the wrong problem to have. If some coder leaves you here, where you have to invoke an *instance* method dynamically without any context within which an object would be possible to create/obtain, then the context is wrong. If you yourself coded the part that passes the interface type class, please share with us what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ernest_k so is what i want possible or not? if it is then how, if it is not then it is not simple as that... I don't have to explain my whole project, I just wrote what I need... It's either possible or it is not...

Comment: The thing you have directly asked for is not possible, and does not make sense.  It might be possible to satisfy your project's needs by redesigning these methods to be static in your interfaces, but if that's not possible, then there's not really a way to do what you want.

Comment: Actually, you can create a class implementing that interface -  coding and compiling it at runtime and using it then. I am currently working on implementation. But I thought there could be another way.

Comment: Create a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` and call [`InvocationHandler.invokeDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html#invokeDefault\(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Method,java.lang.Object...\)). Which still poses some challenges if the default method calls other methods in the interface.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks! Can you provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because default methods are instance methods by definition, we first need an instance of the interface.

Luckily, [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) does exactly that:

```
var proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(IExample.class.getClassLoader(),
    new Class<?>[] {IExample.class}, (m, p, a) -> null);
```

Note that I did pass a very simple invocation handler to the proxy - which will probably yield to errors when the proxy object is used.
This will matter if the default method invokes other methods in the proxy.

Then we can use [`InvocationHandler.invokeDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html#invokeDefault(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Method,java.lang.Object...)) to call the default method:

```
Object result = InvocationHandler.invokeDefault(proxy, IExample.class.getMethod("method"));
```

Again, this will yield to a problem if the default method invokes other methods, including other default methods in the default method body.
If that is required, you need to write a better/more advanced invocation handler.

Also note that `InvocationHandler.invokeDefault` was added in Java 16.